# python requests url to fetch record simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError:

Tags: python, json, odoo

I am trying to fetch table record by using requests method in python it's working fine with other URL request but the URL I have mentioned in the code its actually biometric machine data present int the link in form of a table. I have mentioned the code below please review and let me know have a possible solution. actually I want to fetch attendance record import requests import sys, JSON
import requests
import sys, JSON

```
 import json
 import requests
 import urllib
 url = "http://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all"

 data = requests.get(url).json()
 print(str(data.status_code))
 if data.status_code == 200:
    print(str(data.json()))
```

**Error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/arslan/Documents/Dynexcel/http_request_html_table/http_request.py",
> line 7, in 
> data = requests.get(url).json()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
> return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/**init**.py", line 518, in
> loads
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in
> decode
> obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in
> raw_decode
> return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end()) simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1
> (char 0)

Answer (score 0):

I hope i'm not missing something, but the website you are trying to retrieve data from is obviously html and not json. So python gives you a Decode Error at line:

```
 requests.get(url).json()
```

So you have multiple options to parse this html and extract data. One option would be to get the html with requests and later extract the data with bs4.
I don't see any column "attendance" in this website by the way. Below is a code example, which fetches the highest total score and the name of the related pokemon:

```
import json
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all"

all_pokemons = []
all_scores = []

data = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

all_td = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "cell-total"})

all_pokemon_hrefs = soup.findAll("a", {"class":"ent-name"})




for pokemon in all_pokemon_hrefs:

    all_pokemons.append(pokemon.renderContents().decode("utf-8"))

for td in all_td:

    all_scores.append(td.renderContents().decode("utf-8"))


print("Pokemon {} has the highest total score with: {}".format(str(all_pokemons[all_scores.index(max(all_scores))]),str(max(all_scores))))
```

Comment: okay but what if we try this url(http://124.109.62.143:8081/) actuaaly i need to fetch record from this url by the way

Comment: Ah ok. your code in your question was just an example. Unfortunately it seems like im not allowed to get data from this website, as it requires login.

Comment: yeah it required login.

Comment: i have credentials for login but these are confidential,

Comment: Ok then i don't think it's worth it. Sorry. If the website you are trying to get data from also serves html as the pokemon website you could add the html element you are trying to get to your question so poeple can answer correctly.

Comment: we can pass these credentials as an argument in our request which automaticlly logged in and give the record in response

Comment: yeah your right sir, but now you know what the question is actually , right